# Wrap Multiple <p> elements into <div> between <h3>

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors, tree-traversal

using jQuery I would like to transform this:

```
<h3>Question 1</h3>
<p>Answer 1 P1</p>
<p>Answer 1 P2</p>

<h3>Question 2</h3>
<p>Answer 2 P1</p>
<p>Answer 2 P2</p>
<p>Answer 2 P3</p>
```

Into:

```
<ul>
   <li>
       <h3>Question 1</h3>
       <div>
          <p>Answer 1 P1</p>
          <p>Answer 1 P2</p>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li>
       <h3>Question 2</h3>
       <div>
          <p>Answer 2 P1</p>
          <p>Answer 2 P2</p>
          <p>Answer 2 P3</p>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Any suggestion would be really appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: One approach would be to use jquery to pull all of your initial code and then process that.  Do you have other code "around" your initial code shown above?  (For example... Is all of your code above inside a <div></div> set of tags, or is that all the code on the body of the page.)

Answer (score 7):

I'm using [`nextUntil`](http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) to select all `p` elements after each `h3` element and wrap it in a `div` using [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/), before [adding](http://api.jquery.com/add/) the `h3` element and wrapping that too in a `li`, then appending it to a `ul`. Basically,

```
var ul = $('<ul>').prependTo('body');

$('h3').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('h3')
        .wrapAll('<div>').parent().add(this)
        .wrapAll('<li>').parent().appendTo(ul);
});
```

See: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/SjDe2/1 for a simple demo

Answer (score 0):

Interesting! I'm eagerly waiting for different kind of solutions.

In theory: I would use selector `$('h3, p').each(logic)` to go through all those items and when I encounter tag *h3* I would create *li*, *h3* and *div* and when I would encounter *p* I would add *p* to the *div*